# Adding a penalty of sparsity of the data to the loss function in GAN

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function, generative-adversarial-network

I have implemented a GAN to generate graphs (basically I am generating the adjacency matrix).
The implementation of the training GAN:

```
def find_sparsity(graph):
    return graph.edge_index.shape[1] / (graph.num_nodes ** 2)
def train_gan(loader, discriminator, generator, optimizer_d, optimizer_g, _noise_dim=500, _epochs=100):
    lossesG = []
    lossesD = []
    for epoch in range(1, _epochs):
        for data in loader:
            data_real = data.to(device)
            #noise:
            data_fake = make_geometric_noise_data(_noise_dim).to(device).detach()
            fake_sample = generator(data_fake).detach()
            out_real = discriminator(data_real).detach()
            fake_sample.batch = torch.tensor([1]).to(device)
            out_fake = discriminator(fake_sample)
            #real: 1, fake: 0
            loss_real = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_real, torch.ones_like(out_real))
            loss_fake = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_fake, torch.zeros_like(out_fake))
            lossD = (loss_real + loss_fake)/2
            #discriminator.zero_grad()
            lossD.backward()
            optimizer_d.step()
            #train generator
            lossD_fakeSample = discriminator(fake_sample)
            lossG = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(lossD_fakeSample, torch.ones_like(lossD_fakeSample))
            #generator.zero_grad()
            lossG.backward()
            optimizer_g.step()
        lossesG.append(lossG.item())
        lossesD.append(lossD.item())
        print(f'Epoch: {epoch:03d}, LossG: {lossG:.4f}, LossD: {lossD:.4f}')
```

The real data's adjacancy matrix has low sparsity, however, the generated matrices are not sparse. I want to add a penalty for large sparsity:

```
sparsity_fake = find_sparsity(fake_sample)
sparsity_real = find_sparsity(data_real)
criterion(torch.tensor([sparsity_real]), torch.tensor([sparsity_fake]))
```

and

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

However, when I use this sparsity in the loss function (`lossG += sparsity_loss`), I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me to add the sparsity penalty to the loss function.

Solution: I am rewrapping the sparsity with torch.tensor which detaches it from the computational graph.

Comment: You might need to post a minimal working example; otherwise it's unclear how `find_sparsity` is defined and where the error happens.

Comment: @Cheng Thanks a lot for mentioning this. I am adding the definition of the find-sparsity.

Comment: My question has been answered in: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/adding-a-penalty-of-sparsity-of-the-data-to-the-loss-function-in-gan/174033/2?u=maryam_haghifam